# Instant Dynamic Feature Module vs instant application

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-app-links

I've read several page on documentation, but seems its not quite clear, what structure should be done if u need to have

> [instant app](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle)

what should be available **only from special link**, not from play store itself (**try now** button). Will this structure work for this case ? [source video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdfStuj-MuA) [image]

I mean do we need **separate instant application** in this case, or it should be **instant dynamic module** ?